# PHP inside a PHP if else statement - wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement

I basically want to show some php if it's inside the category work, I know how to do the if else statement and the output php on their own but not quite sure how to combine the two, if someone could enlighten me it would be much appreciated. The basic code is below, i'm guessing i'm not allowed to have a `<?php inside a <?php?`

Many thanks!

```
<?php // Outputting related work if in work category
  if ( in_category( 'work' )) { 
    echo "

    <section class='work'>

      <h2>Also of interest</h2>

      <?php query_posts('category_name=work&posts_per_page=3&order=DSC&offset=1&orderby=ID'); 
        if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

      <article>
        <a href='<?php the_permalink() ?>'>
          <?php the_post_thumbnail();?>
          <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
          <span>Redesign</span>
          <?php the_excerpt($strip_teaser); ?>
        </a>
      </article>

      <?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query();?>

      <a class='all' href='/work'>&rarr; View all work</a>

    </section> <!-- end work -->
";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP is a templating language, use it as such:

```
<?php // Outputting related work if in work category
  if ( in_category( 'work' )) { 
?>

    <section class='work'>

      <h2>Also of interest</h2>

      <?php query_posts('category_name=work&posts_per_page=3&order=DSC&offset=1&orderby=ID'); 
        if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

      <article>
        <a href='<?php the_permalink() ?>'>
          <?php the_post_thumbnail();?>
          <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
          <span>Redesign</span>
          <?php the_excerpt($strip_teaser); ?>
        </a>
      </article>

      <?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query();?>

      <a class='all' href='/work'>&rarr; View all work</a>

    </section> <!-- end work -->
<?php
}
?>
```

Code that is not enclosed in `<?php ?>` tags is output as is to the browser. Every time the webserver discovers a `<?php` starting tag it gives control to the PHP interpreter which then executes the code enclosed in that tags.

Comment: Thanks, that makes things a lot easier!

Answer (score 0):

You are putting php tags in a echo statement, if you want to put a while loop in some text i would quit de echo with `";`, make your while loop like so `while(hava_posts()) {` in between here you echo your article like `echo "<article></article>";` then you close your while with a bracket `}` and call your `wp_reset_query();` function.

Comment: Thanks, feel pretty stupid now, should have noticed I had the entire thing in an echo, thanks for your help :)

Comment: Certainly have :) think the best plan of action is for me to do this as a seperate php file and use a php include otherwise the code is going to get pretty messy!

Answer (score 0):

What you basically should do is:

```
$str = "Let's output some HTML here <h1>";
while ($x) {
   $str .= "This is my ";
}
$str .= "title</h1>";
echo $str;
```

So you just break `$str` and then use concatenation operator `.`